# Protecting a wire linked to a power supply

Tags: power-supply, wiring, wire-terminals

I have a power supply of this kind: https://www.makerlab-electronics.com/my_uploads/2017/06/36V-Switching-Power-Supply-01.jpg
and wires linked to it like on https://i.ytimg.com/vi/DrZ8oupvzSE/hqdefault.jpg

But I often need to move all of it, this makes the wires turn and eventually the wires break. Would someone know which additional system could protect the wires, please?

Comment: P clip the wires to a baseboard that supports the power supply.

Comment: Use proper crimp-on terminals on the wires.

Answer (score 3):

The power supply that you show is not meant to be used standalone in a portable manner. Instead it is supposed to be placed inside of some type of enclosure. In an enclosure the wiring to the terminal block on the power supply would be harnessed and secured in some manner so that it stays in a particular location and does not freely move around. The securing method will vary by application but could include the use of P-clamps, self adhesive pads with cable ties, or even special hold downs integrated directly in the enclosure design.

When done correctly things like the AC power cord will be retained through the enclosure wall with a strain relief or plugged through an AC inlet module. The enclosure can the be moved around without concern that the internal wiring is being flexed, tugged or subject to breaking.

There is also a safety aspect to this too. An open power supply like you have shown leaves open access to AC terminals that can be touched by fingers, tools or other loose bits of hardware or wire. This can be dangerous to the health and well being of the user. There are a whole set of rules for safety that must be followed if you are to apply for a product to be UL, CE or CSA certified. A proper enclosure is a fundamental part of this.